# Is there a way to update a pic(bmp) in visual studio C#?

Tags: c#

In a program I am writing I work with images. I do several things with them and in the end (of a process) I invoke a function `drawPicFrame`

```
private void drawPicFrame(Bitmap bmp)
{
 picImage.Image = bmp;
}
```

It works great. However when debugging, I have noticed that the pic control does not get updated until a operation is concluded and the GUI event loop is in charge. So for example say I put red dots all over the place in bmp in `operation1()` , and I put a breakpoint inside this operation1, these dots won't be seen until I leave operation1.

My question is, is there a way that I can update the bmp *and* see this reflected while I am still debugging?

(I know that I can modify my code so that instead of operation1 executing multiple loops, just execute one and then call drawPicFrame, but this involves a huge modification of the code just for debugging which is not ideal

Comment: You may need to update your pic in a separate thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you can reach your control from that point in code, you can call picImage.Refresh() ... but please be aware that you should only do this on the UI thread (read: the thread that created picImage)